# Why umask 555 is setting the file mods to "222" instead of "111"?

Tags: command-line, permissions, umask

I know that:

1. A file default mod is `666`
2. `umask` value will be removed from default mods.

So why when I set the "umask" to `555` it doesn't set newly created file's permissions to `111`? instead it's setting them to `222`

Comment: You cannot normally create an executable file using umask; you can only change a file's permissions to make it executable. The only exceptions to this rule are when creating a directory or compiling a program to create an executable binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Because with a `5` you are removing the `read (4)` and `executable (1)` bit, so you end up with only `write (2)`.

---

#### Explanation:

With `555` you are not setting default executable bit on.

```
It's wrong          =>          (6 - 5 = 1)
```

We got these mods:

- 4 = Read
- 2 = Write
- 1 = Executable

The only way that I can create a `5` is from `4 + 1`, so `5` actually means:

```
   4 (Read) + 1  (Executable)   =    5
```

It means "remove" executable and read mods if they're are being set.

In other words, with `umask 555` you are removing the read ( 4 ) and executable ( 1 ) bit from default file mode ( 6 ) which brings us to the ( 2 ), because in a 6 we only have a 4 and 2 to remove (not any 1):

```
6  =  4   +   2
```

You removal only effects the 4, so the file ends up with `222`.

#### In binary

Think of it in binary:

```
1 -> 001
2 -> 010
3 -> 011
4 -> 100
5 -> 101
6 -> 110
7 -> 111
```

File default mode is 666 (110 110 110), and our `umask` value is `555` (101 101 101):

```
  Decimal title  ->         421 421 421
  666 in binary  ->         110 110 110
- 555 in binary  ->       - 101 101 101
                           _____________
                            010 010 010
                             2   2   2
                            -w- -w- -w-
```

See? we ended up to the -w-w-w-, or `222`.

Comment: good explanation as always....

Answer (score 2):

The result umask value is **mask & 0777** (*bit wise and*)

When mask is 0555
Than **0555 & 0777** result with **0222**

> **[nixCraft understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)**
>
> **Task: Calculating The Final Permission For FILES**
>
> You can simply subtract the umask from the base permissions to
>   determine the final permission for file as follows:
>
> ```
> 666 – 022 = 644
>
> File base permissions : 666
> umask value : 022
> subtract to get permissions of new file (666-022) : 644 (rw-r–r–)
> ```
>
> **Task: Calculating The Final Permission For DIRECTORIES**
>
> You can simply subtract the umask from the base permissions to
>   determine the final permission for directory as follows:
>
> ```
> 777 – 022 = 755
>
> Directory base permissions : 777
> umask value : 022
> Subtract to get permissions of new directory (777-022) : 755 (rwxr-xr-x)
> ```

The source of the difference between `touch file` and `mkdir dir`:

> Note: as specify in this [Unix Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102075/why-are-666-the-default-file-creation-permissions)
>
> how the permission bits are hard-coded into the standard utilities.
>   Here are some relevant lines from two files in the `coreutils` package
>   that contains the source code for both `touch(1)` and `mkdir(1)`,
>   among others:
>
> `mkdir.c`:
>
> ```
> if (specified_mode)
>    {   
>      struct mode_change *change = mode_compile (specified_mode);
>      if (!change)
>        error (EXIT_FAILURE, 0, _("invalid mode %s"),
>               quote (specified_mode));
>      options.mode = mode_adjust (S_IRWXUGO, true, umask_value, change,
>                                   &options.mode_bits);
>      free (change);
>    }   
>   else
>     options.mode = S_IRWXUGO & ~umask_value;
> }
> ```
>
> In other words, if the mode is not specified, set it to `S_IRWXUGO`
>   (read: 0777) modified by the `umask_value`.
>
> `touch.c` is even clearer:
>
> ```
> int default_permissions =
>   S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH;
> ```
>
> That is, give read and write permissions to everyone (read: 0666),
>   which will be modified by the process `umask` on file creation, of
>   course.
>
> You may be able to get around this programmatically only: i.e. while
>   creating files from within either a C program, where you make the
>   system calls directly or from within a language that allows you to
>   make a low-level syscall (see for example Perl's `sysopen` under
>   `perldoc -f sysopen`).
>
> [man umask](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html)
>
> umask() sets the calling process's file mode creation mask (umask) to
>          **mask & 0777** (i.e., only the file permission bits of mask are used),
>          and returns the previous value of the mask.

Comment: For the files it's not 777, it's 666 ... `strace touch a |& grep open` outputs: `open("a", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3`, and for directories: `strace mkdir a1 |& grep 777` >
`mkdir("a1", 0777)`  .

Comment: @Ravexina - as mentioned in the [unix.se] Q&A which I added to my answer, `touch` uses default `0666` mask, which added  in `bit wise and` with  the `umask_value`. While `mkdir` uses a default `0777` mask  which added  in `bit wise and` with  the `umask_value`.

Comment: Yeah, the default mod depends on the program, also `umask` itself can be ignored by the programs like compilers, `chmod`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

#### Definition

Roughly speaking, in general, the on bits of a mask switch off (if not already off) the bits of what it is masking.

More precisely, in this particular case, the resulting mode of a newly created file or folder follows the following bitwise operation:

```
result = mode & !mask
```

where `result` is the resulting mode, `mode` is the usual mode (666 for files and 777 for folders), and `!mask` is the bitwise negation of `mask`, the set mask.

#### Examples

Masking write (2) permission on the left, and read (4) and execution (1) permissions on the right.

```
 folder                file                    folder                file
(7) 111     mask       110 (6)                (7) 111     mask       110 (6)
    101 <-- !010 -->   101                        010 <-- !101 -->   010
  &-----     (2)     &-----                     &-----     (5)     &-----
(5) 101                100 (4)                (2) 010                010 (2)
```

#### Notes

Observe from the last example that **masking does not coincide with subtraction** (6-5=1 in both, decimal and binary notation).